# How to automate helm package --sign non-interactively in bash

Tags: bash, gnupg, kubernetes-helm

I am writing a bash script on a machine without expect.
The script automates the build of a helm (v2.9.1) chart.

I've got to the part in the script where it runs a

`helm package --sign --key 'mykey' --keyring 'path/to/keyring' -d chartdir chart`

and because helm prompts for the passphrase of the gpg key I created in order to use provenance files (a requirement), I cannot script around the soliciting of the passphrase, which I would like to prompt for separately as the script is part of a CI/CD build chain.

I have tried using

`yes $promptedPassPhrase | helm package --sign...`

and I got

`xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744071562067968 bytes (237568 bytes allocated)`

I also tried plain old

`echo $promptedPassPhrase | helm package --sign...`

and I got

`Error: inappropriate ioctl for device`

I also tried `script` and got the same response.  As I do not have expect on the server, I cannot `expect` my way round it, so I'm stumped as to how to automate the helm package command and am not going to use a key without a passphrase as it is bad practice.

Comment: `yes "$passphrase"` in a script is *even worse* practice. `yes` is an external command -- not part of the shell -- so it gets its own entry in the process table... meaning you're putting your passphrase in `ps` for everyone (all users on the system, including untrusted accounts like `nobody`) to see.

Comment: ...backing away from that implementation detail, though -- you can always implement your own `pinentry` tool and configure GPG to invoke it when a passphrase or PIN is needed. Set `use-agent` in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, set `pinentry-program` to your program that retrieves the password from wherever it's stored (hopefully securely!) in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, and there you are.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy agreed on the use of Yes.  Even trying it was like eating a dirty burger.

Comment: (BTW, if this is used in any kind of situation that actually matters, I'd tend to suggest having your private key stored in dedicated hardware -- gpg-agent can be used to communicate with a PKCS#11 smartcard, a YubiKey, etc; that way an attacker can't copy the private keying material off-host even if they do manage to 0wn the box. There are of course all the usual tricks to try to make a process harder to trace, but they're inadequate against a sufficiently competent attacker -- and these days, "sufficiently competent" can just mean running a [sysdig](https://sysdig.com/opensource/) trace).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how long this has been the case, or exactly which versions this works on, but [this doc page](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/v2.12.0-rc.1/docs/provenance.md) says:

> If your PGP private key has a passphrase, [...] You can set the `HELM_KEY_PASSPHRASE` environment variable to that passphrase in case you don't want to be prompted to enter the passphrase.

This works for me on `v2.13.1`. It looks like it was added in [October of 2018](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/4778), so my guess is that it was first available in [v2.12.0-rc.1](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.12.0-rc.1).

Although this doesn't directly answer the OP's question (since they asked about `v2.9.1`), it will hopefully help anyone who ends up here because they (like me the first time round) missed that line in the doc.

Comment: It doesn't work for me in helm 3.1,

Comment: Indeed. Looks like they removed that functionality in Helm 3. They did add a workaround in 3.4, though. See [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/8394) for the pull request. There is also an [issue thread](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8455) on using stdin as a workaround for versions between 3.0 and 3.4